# Is a subordinating clause always an incomplete sentence?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Cambridge University:

> When a clause follows these (subordinating) conjunctions , it becomes a subordinate
> clause, which needs a main clause to make a complete sentence.
> [Link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/conjunctions)

Let's take a look at this example:

> *We went home early because we were tired.*

Here, *'because we were tired'*  described as a incomplete thought and sentence due to mentioned grammar rules because it has followed a subordinating conjunction.

Well, in general, if someone in a conversation suddenly says, "because we were tired" It is an incomplete thought and sentence indeed.

But what if conversation goes like this:

> A: We went home early.
> B: [I know] Because you were tired.

Here it isn't an incomplete thought even though the sentence has started with 'because' which we call it a subordinating conjunction.

Contradiction begins here. The clause 'you were tired' follows a subordinating conjunction but it doesn't need a main clause to make a complete sentence. It's already a complete sentence but with a subordinating conjunction.

Comment: When a clause is introduced by a subordinator, the whole sequence including the subordinator is a subordinate clause. In, for example, "I know [that Ed is a good teacher]" it is the whole bracketed sequence that is a subordinate clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"You were tired." is a complete sentence.

"...because you were tired." is not a complete sentence. It is the presence of the conjunction that makes it need a clause to be subordinate to.

There isn't any contradiction. Yes, in speech you can say "Because you were tired.", where both parties understand what was omitted, and that can make sense. But, people don't always speak in complete sentences.

Comment: therefore, you mean if we find a clause that follows a subordinating conjunction but it's understandable and complete, there is always an omitted part?

Comment: I think so, unless you have an example to the contrary?

Comment: That's the point, and It's completely logical; I didn't know main clauses can be omitted as well.

Comment: A subordinate clause is an embedded clause that is dependent on some other element in the sentence. Modern grammar defines "because" as a preposition. "You were tired" is a clause that is dependent on the prep "because", and it thus qualifies as a subordinate clause.

Answer (score 4):

A string of words may be a "complete thought" in the sense that it conveys understandable information. That is not the same as being a grammatically correct sentence.

Sure, if someone asked, "Why did you stop?" and you replied, "Because I was tired", we all understood what was meant. That does not make your response a complete, grammatically correct sentence.

Just like, if someone asked, "Where is my fork?" and you  replied, "On the table", we all understand the meaning, but that does not make "On the table" a complete, grammatically correct sentence.

I could give many examples of strings of words that convey useful information but are not complete sentences. In casual conversation, we do this all the time. If someone asks, "Who was that man I saw you with yesterday at the restaurant?", most people would reply with something like, "My friend Bob". Very few would reply with a complete sentence, like, "The man that you saw me with yesterday at the restaurant was my friend Bob."

Comment: So can we conclude that every clause with a subordinating conjunction at the beginning that has a complete thought has an omitted part? Like: [I stopped] Because I was tired. Is the main clause [I stopped] omitted here?

Comment: @KavehBehnia  A subordinate clause is not defined semantically but grammatically. It's an embedded clause that is dependent on some other element in the sentence.

Comment: I still remember teachers who expected us to answer in complete sentences. So if they asked "What is the sum of two and three?" you were supposed to respond something like "Two plus three is five." But this kind of repetition of the question is redundant and not common in casual speech (when done, it's usually for some rhetoric purpose, like emphasis).

Comment: Just saying "Because I was tired" is nonsensical. It must be providing a reason for something. For instance "You've stopped going to the gym?" "Because I was tired." Here you could replace the response with the complete sentence "I've stopped going to the gym because I was tired."

Comment: I'd argue against using "grammatically correct sentence" to describe this usage, since there is absolutely nothing inherently incorrect about partial sentences, and I would suggest instead the term "grammatically complete sentence".

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but all your examples are answers to questions, which is generally regarded as a special case.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you Ok. Suppose you are walking down the street with a friend and suddenly he says, "A rabid dog!" That's not a complete sentence. It conveys information. I would presume he meant something like, "A rabid dog is attacking us".

Comment: @DewiMorgan Hmm, one could quibble about definitions. I'd say that an incomplete sentence is, by definition, "grammatically incorrect". It certainly can convey information, as I discussed above. I don't think "grammatically incorrect" necessarily implies "does not convey information". If someone says, "There are a man at the door", that's grammatically incorrect (subject/verb agreement), but any listener would surely know what he meant. Maybe we'd question if he meant "there is one man" versus "there are two or more men".

Comment: @Jay I like that example, I think it should be in the answer.

Comment: @Jay Hardly a quibble, I think your answer is arguing that sentence fragment usage does not need to be corrected, but using "incorrect" means that something needs correcting. Unless that's what you actually meant, your use of the word makes your answer... incorrect.

Comment: In response to the question "Who's at the door?" the answer "There are a man at the door" is grammatically incorrect (=in need of correction). The answer "A man." is a 100% grammatically correct sentence fragment (=no need to correct this, you can print it in a book without your editor correcting it, and can submit it in English Language Learner homework, and not lose any marks).

Comment: @DewiMorgan Hmm. What in the world is a "grammatically correct sentence fragment"? That's like saying a "legal crime" or an "honest liar". There are certainly times when a grammatically incorrect sentence, such as a fragment, is perfectly good and appropriate, but that doesn't make it grammatically correct. Anyway, there's probably no point arguing about this so feel free to get the last word.

Comment: @barmar Yes! When I was in school teachers regularly insisted that answers to questions on tests must be complete sentences. My chemistry teacher once asked why we repeated the question in our answers on his tests, and several students said that was required by other teachers. He said, "If I ask what compound is produced when you mix two chemicals, just tell me the name of the compound. You don't have to say, 'Yes indeed, when you mix A and B there is a chemical reaction'."